# Jquery to get the selected radio button value

Tags: jquery

i have 3 set of radio buttons while selecting any one of them i have to get the value of that radio.

iam using following code

```
Daily<input type="radio" id="rad" value="daily" />
Weekly<input type="radio" id="rad" name="case" value="weekly"/>
None<input type="radio" id="rad" name="case" value="none"/>
alert("rad------"+$('#rad').val());
```

it alerts the radio button value first time only and  multiple radio button seems to be as selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of selected radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id of an element must be unique, so in this case you need to find the checked radio button with name `case`

For that you can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) along with [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
Daily <input type="radio" id="rad" name="case" value="daily" />
Weekly <input type="radio" id="rad" name="case" value="weekly" />
None <input type="radio" id="rad" name="case" value="none" />

alert("rad------"+$('input[type="radio"][name="case"]:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be in how you are detecting the change in event, you can do something like this:

```
$('container input:radio').click(function(){
    alert("rad------"+$(this).val());
});
```

notes

:radio is short for [type=radio]

substitute container for the container, or use input#radio in the case of your example. Generally it isn't a good idea to assign the same id to a bunch of inputs

Answer (score 0):

Just to be a pedant - as Arun P Johny wrote IDs must be unique, but in his example he left the duplicate IDs in.

It should be:

```
Daily <input type="radio" name="case" value="daily" />
Weekly <input type="radio" name="case" value="weekly" />
None <input type="radio" name="case" value="none" />
alert("rad------"+$('input[type="radio"][name="case"]:checked').val());
```

See [Two radio buttons share one "id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305953/two-radio-buttons-share-one-id) for more details.