# How to check the radio button by default

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Here is my radio button.

```
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio" value=1>
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio" value=2>
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio" value=3>
```

In the script i want to check the third radio button

`$('#MyRadio').attr('checked',true);` but it is not checking any radio button.

`var target = '3';`

How can i check the radio button with the `id="MyRadio"` and with `value=3` ?

Comment: Forget to close type `<input type="radio" id="MyRadio" value=1>`

Comment: @Saty  Yes, that was the type in the question. I now corrected. How can i do that .. ?\

Comment: an Id should ALWAYS be unique. Please use "name" instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305953/two-radio-buttons-share-one-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Concerning boolean attributes, consider a DOM element defined by the HTML markup , and assume it is in a JavaScript variable named elem:

```
elem.checked    true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
$( elem ).prop( "checked" )     true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
elem.getAttribute( "checked" )  "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (1.6)   "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (1.6.1+)    "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (pre-1.6)   true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```

**CORRECT:**

```
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio3" value=3>
$("MyRadio3").checked
```

It doesnt make sense if you name 3 elements the same id. You rather should use classes.

Comment: God, I wanted to do it in `JQuery` not directly giving the `checked` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `id` should be unique so change your `id` to `class` instead.

So HTML becomes:

```
<input type="radio" class="MyRadio" value=1>
<input type="radio" class="MyRadio" value=2>
<input type="radio" class="MyRadio" value=3>
```

Using Jquery > 1.9

```
$(".MyRadio:radio[value=3]").prop("checked", true)
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6s31h8d/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#MyRadio').val(3);` it should work

Comment: how does this check anything?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a "

try this following code

```
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio1" value=1>
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio2" value=2>
<input type="radio" id="MyRadio3" value=3>
                  ^




$("#MyRadio3").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Change it from "true" to "checked."

For jQuery 1.9 or higher use: (possible since 1.6)

```
$("#MyRadio3").prop("checked", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=type][value=2]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

You can try this to checked radio button based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Just give a name attribute to your radio buttons.

```
$('input:radio[name="MyRadio"]').filter('[value="3"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you're missing a quote after you set the type to radio. Second issue is using the same ID on multiple elements, a class is better suited for that job.

The javascript should be along the lines of this:

```
$('.MyRadio').eq(2).attr('checked', true)
```

First is the selector using the class name, Second is the eq function which gets the element by its index from the array. Third is setting the checked attribute just as you had done :).

https://jsfiddle.net/un5pfee2/